# Qual diferença entre simulador e emulador?

Tags: terminologia

Atualmente estou desenvolvendo aplicações híbridas e **supostamente**, digo supostamente, estou "simulando" minhas aplicações no *browser* e as vezes em uma máquina virtual, sendo para Android o AVD (*Android Virtual Device*). Mas na verdade, não sei exatamente se estou "simulando" ou "emulando".

Qual diferença entre simulador e emulador?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Simulação é imitar. Emulação é reproduzir.

Baseado [nessa resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2175146/1700943), que é oposta a [essa outra resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584617/simulator-or-emulator-what-is-the-difference), e também naquele livro célebre que ficou famoso na época do lançamento do filme Matrix ([Simulacres et Simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacra_and_Simulation)):

**Simulação** tem a ver com a possibilidade de imitar o comportamento de um sistema sem necessariamente reproduzir seus componentes ou saber como ele funciona internamente.

**Emulação** tem a ver com a possibilidade de reconstruir um sistema a partir do entendimento do funcionamento do mesmo, de forma que o resultado seja bastante semelhante ao original.

Um exemplo ilustrativo: No filme "[Enigma de Outro Mundo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084787/)", o alienígena tem um processo de reprodução que a partir do DNA da sua vítima replica uma nova pessoa, imitando quase que completamente seus órgãos, tecidos, etc. Isso seria uma **emulação**. Já no filme "[Homem Bicentenário](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0182789/)", um robô tenta imitar a aparência e comportamento dos humanos. Isso seria uma **simulação**.

No seu caso, o programa que reproduz o comportamento do dispositivo Android é um emulador porque você pode colocar seu código que roda no dispositivo real e ele funcionará da mesma forma. Já, se a aplicação rodando no browser for uma aplicação completamente diferente da que roda no dispositivo, porém o resultado para o usuário é o mesmo, então a aplicação é um simulador.